# 'Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.'

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am sending Customer and all MembershipTypes to the Edit view from Customer Controller because I need both, if you can tell me how to send both in VIEW not in ViewBag.Message
as well as why my app throws error everytime I edit an item please

My customer class which has a many - to one relationship with membershipType class:

```
 public class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            this.Movies = new HashSet<Movie>();
        }
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSubscribedToNewsletter { get; set; }
        public int CurrentMembershipTypeId { get; set; }
        public MembershipType CurrentMembershipType { get; set;}
        public ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
```

My MembershipType class:

```
public class MembershipType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public short SignupFee { get; set; }
        public byte DurationInMonths { get; set; }
        public byte DiscountRate { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

        // public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movie { get; set; }
    }
```

My CustomerController: get Function for customer Edit:

```
  public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer = iCustomerRepository.GetCustomerByID(id);
            var membershipTypes = iMembershipTypeRepository.GetMembershipTypes();
            ViewBag.Message = membershipTypes;
            return View(customer);
        }
```

Post action for Customer Edit:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Customer customer)
        {
            Customer Customer = new Customer();
            Customer.id = customer.id;
            Customer.Name = customer.Name;
            Customer.IsSubscribedToNewsletter = customer.IsSubscribedToNewsletter;
            Customer.CurrentMembershipTypeId = customer.CurrentMembershipTypeId;
            iCustomerRepository.UpdateCustomer(Customer);
            iCustomerRepository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Customer");
        }
```

Customer Form Edit View:

```
<form action="/Customer/Edit" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Id:</td>
            <td><label for="CustomerId">ID:</label></td>
            <td><input id="CustomerId" type="number" name="CustomerId" value="@Model.id" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input id="CustomerName" type="text" name="CustomerName" value="@Model.Name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>IsSubscribedToNewLetter:</td>
            <td><input id="CustomerisSubscribedToNewsLetter" type="text" name="CustomerisSubscribedToNewsLetter" value="@Model.IsSubscribedToNewsletter" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MembershipType:</td>
            <td>
                <select id="MembershipTypeId" name="MembershipTypeId">
                    @foreach (var membershipType in @ViewBag.Message)
                    {
                        <option value=@membershipType.Id>
                            @membershipType.Id
                        </option>
                    }
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
```

Customer repository class:

namespace WebApplication2.Repositories.CustomersRepositories

{

```
public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository, IDisposable

{

    private CustomerContext context;



    public CustomerRepository(CustomerContext context)

    {

        this.context = context;

    }

    //public short GetMembershipTypeSignupFee()
    //{
    //    var Customers = context.Customers.ToList();
    //    foreach (var customer in Customers)
    //    {
    //       return  customer.CurrentMembershipType.SignupFee;
    //    }

    //}

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()

    {

        return context.Customers.ToList();

    }

    public Customer GetCustomerByID(int Id)

    {

        return context.Customers.Find(Id);

    }

    public void InsertCustomer(Customer customer)

    {

        context.Customers.Add(customer);

    }

    //public void InsertMany()

    //{

    //    context.Customers.AddRange(context.Customers);

    //}

    public void DeleteCustomer(int Id)

    {

        Customer customer = context.Customers.Find(Id);

        context.Customers.Remove(customer);

    }

    public void DeleteAllCustomers()

    {

        context.Customers.RemoveRange(context.Customers);

        context.SaveChanges();

    }

    public void UpdateCustomer(Customer customer)

    {

        context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;

    }

    public void Save()

    {

        context.SaveChanges();

    }



    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)

    {

        if (!this.disposed)

        {

            if (disposing)

            {

                context.Dispose();

            }

        }

        this.disposed = true;

    }



    public void Dispose()

    {

        Dispose(true);

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: When and where does the error appear? Does it appear during update-database?

Comment: What do EntityValidationErrors say?

Comment: it appears in the customer repository                                                            public void Save()

        {

            context.SaveChanges();

        }

Comment: When you debug when the exception happens when you inspect the exception, what does the EntityValidationErrors  property contain? This information holds the key to solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Since you haven't shown the repository method, this is a guess.*

`iCustomerRepository.UpdateCustomer(Customer);` tries to add a new customer and database rightly rejects it because a record with the given id already exists.

The repository method need to load the existing customer and then change it's properties. BTW. It's common to have `SaveChanges` inside the repository call rather then the controller calling it.

Something like the following.

```
var Upadate(Customer customer) {
    // Authorization code here maybe

    using( var context = ... ) {
       var dbCustomer = c.Customers.FirstOrDefault( c => c.Id = customer.id );
       if( dbCustomer == null ) throw new KeyNotFoundException("Customer not found!");
       dbCustomer.A = ...;
       dbCustomer.B = ...;


       context.SaveChanges();
}
```

*I would encourage you to use names starting with a lowercase letter for variables.*

Comment: I have added the CustoemrRepository class above. this might help